# Printing confusion matrix for multiclass random forest in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am working with sklearn.RandomForestClassifier and I have 11 classes. My data is in the dataframe, all variables are hot-encoded.  The classes are strings such as 'Potato', 'Tomato','Straberry', etc.

When I'm trying to print confusion matrix, I get the following:

```
print(pd.crosstab(y_test, y_pred))

Error: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

When I am passing an index:

```
print(pd.crosstab(y_test, y_pred, index = [0]))

Error:crosstab() got multiple values for argument 'index'
```

What would be the best way to address this?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you need to pass the argument "index" to crosstab and not an index which helps you traverse through a list. You can find the correct method and more details about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

You can also use the following code to plot a Confusion Matrix in Sci-Kit Learn

This code gets all your labels from your training data that are used for the Confusion Matrix

```
label=y_train.unique()
label=np.sort(label)
```

This code imports the Confusion Matrix and plots it. `plt.cm.Blues` is used for the Color Scheme and `clf` is your classifier be sure to change it with what you have named your Classifier.

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
cm=plot_confusion_matrix(clf,X_test, y_test,labels=label,cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```